# How to scrape a nested element in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to scrape this URL:

```
http://movietube.cc/search.php
```

I need each movie name, images and link. I have tried to nest the `<tr>` element

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://movietube.cc/search.php');


// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('tr ') as $element) 
       echo $element->val. '<br>';
 ?>
```

I can't get it done. I am new to scraping, can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Don't know your tool, but shouldn't it be 'tr' without a following blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//set POST variables
$fields = array(
    'c' => song,
    'a' => retrieve,
    'p' => urlencode('{"Page":"1","NextToken":"","VideoYoutubeType":"English","Genere":"","Year":"","Sortby":"Score"}')
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://movietube.cc/index.php');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

$html = str_get_html($str); //echo $html;

$img = array(); $title = array(); $url = array();

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('a[target=_blank] img[bgcolor=##000000]') as $element) {
    $img[] = $element->src;
    //echo $element->src. '<br>';
}

// Find all titles 
foreach($html->find('div.dtl h1.text a[target=_blank]') as $element) {
    $title[] = $element->plaintext;
    //echo $element->plaintext. '<br>';
}

// Find all urls 
foreach($html->find('div.dtl h1.text a[target=_blank]') as $element) {
    $url[] = $element->href;
    //echo $element->href. '<br>';
}

//Print results
echo "<pre>"; print_r($img);   echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($title); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($url);   echo "</pre>";

?>
```

This is the code you need to be using: You can edit the POST variables,if you want to get results for other languages or other stuff. I decided to place all the images titles and urls in arrays (img, title and url).

Comment: simply do `$img[] = $element->src;` otherwise your array will be at most 1 element length.
Or do `$img[$i++] = $element->src;` but I prefer the former.

Comment: Right, I was busy with finding the data to send as post that I didn't test the code ;)

Comment: Is that getting data from the site?

Comment: Yes, basically when you asked for search.php, search.php sent a request to index.php with the parameters found in $fields['p'] that's why we are taking directly the data from index.php.
Do you know how to accept an answer?